# How to determine which Java types (e.g. LocalDate) are safely hashable?

Tags: java, hashcode, localdate

Background: I want to take two sets of records and deduplicate them based on a unique key. So I've written up a class that can be dedicated to the purpose (serving as the key in a Map or Set). Example:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Key {

  private final String email;
  private final LocalDate start;
  private final LocalDate end;
}
```

Here, as far as I can tell, lombok should generate `hashCode` methods that will serve the purpose. However, the official docs state the following:

> This is a value-based class; use of identity-sensitive operations (including reference equality (==), identity hash code, or synchronization) on instances of LocalDate may have unpredictable results and should be avoided. The equals method should be used for comparisons ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)).

Now, the first part of my question is whether I should be worried about these "unpredictable results." I understand the distinction between value and reference types, and I want to use `LocalDate` specifically because it is a value type. Is this text just try to warn consumers of `LocalDate` not to treat it as a reference type, or does the unpredictable behaviour go deeper than that?

Here is the second part of the question (consider it a bonus question). I've done some spot tests in which I've called `hashCode` on separate instances of `LocalDate` representing the same date, and it seems to behave as a value type should, e.g., `LocalDate.parse("2022-01-01").hashCode() == LocalDate.parse("2022-01-01").hashCode()` is true. But I would like to have higher confidence that this will work across a range of inputs. What would be the best way to establish that `LocalDate` is going to behave itself in the way I expect? Is there any way to do so that isn't basically looping over a bunch of dates and checking `hashCode` equality?

Comment: The paragraph you've quoted talks about using the *identity* hash code - not `hashCode()`, which should be fine. Note that `LocalDate` is still a class, and therefore a reference type - it's just a *value-based* class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"identity hashcode" != "hashcode"

The paragraph you quoted talks about the *identity* hash code, which is returned by [`System.identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)), or by `hashCode` if the class does not implement its own `hashCode` method.

`LocalDate` *does* implement its own `hashCode` method, so you don't need to worry at all here.

Think about what it would imply if `hashCode` returns different hash codes for two `LocalDate`s that are the same - this break the general contract of [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())!

> If two objects are equal according to the equals method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Additional Notes:

`LocalDate` is a [value-based class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html), which has a few notable properties. Importantly:

> - the class's methods treat instances as *freely substitutable* when equal, meaning that interchanging any two instances x and y that are equal according to `equals()` produces no visible change in the behavior of the class's methods;
> - the class does not provide any instance creation mechanism that promises a unique identity on each method call — in particular, any factory method's contract must allow for the possibility that if two independently-produced instances are equal according to `equals()`, they may also be equal according to `==`;

This is why you are strongly discouraged to do operations that depend on "which object it is" (aka "identity"), like `==`, `identityHashCode` and synchronisation, and it is said that these operations' behaviour on value-based classes may change in a future release.

```
// no guarantee as to what the result will be
LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 16) == LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 16)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just recently started learning java, and did not pick up on `value-based class` as a technical term, or the distinction between the different kinds of hashCode.